# How to stop vector3 from moving GameObject up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started using unity, and I'm trying to make a player character that can move along the x axis and nothing else. I used [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unity/unity_basic_movement_scripting.htm) website to try and achieve movement. However, the player can still move up on the Y axis.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

  public float speed;
  public Rigidbody body;

  void Update() {
     float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
     float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
     body.velocity = new Vector2(h * speed, v * speed);
   }
}
```

I also have code that makes the player jump properly. Is there a way make the player not move up from this script, but still jump properly on the other script?

Comment: What do you think `body.velocity = new Vector2(h * speed, v * speed);` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is taking the input from both the horizontal and vertical axes. You are then setting both the X and Y components of velocity of your rigidbody. To only move in one axis, just provide a value for one of the axes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {

  public float speed;
  public Rigidbody body;

  void Update() {
     float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
     body.velocity = new Vector2(h * speed, body.velocity.y);
   }
}
```

I would need to see your jump code, but as I am accounting for your existing Y velocity in this movement code, it should work.